# what's is "Schwinger average vacuum state"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I just heard this term for the first time. what is it? can't find something on the internet about it? does anybody know something about this?

Comment: where did you hear it? In a lecture? If so, are there lecture notes? Give us the context

Comment: @st.vit yes, in a lecture, but there are no lecture notes. my university is quite retarded actually.